# jQuery plugin Tokenize2 loaded into Modern Script Editor webpart throws error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tokenize2 is not a function

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery-ui

I'm using a jQuery plugin in a SharePoint page. The plugin is available at https://github.com/dragonofmercy/Tokenize2

It works great when my HTML and JavaScript is outside of a SharePoint page. The error only appears when the code is inside of a SharePoint page.

Here are all the external libraries I'm calling.

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="localurl/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="localurl/tokenize2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="localurl/tokenize2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="localurl/SimpleTableCellEditor.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.7/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xls/0.7.4-a/xls.core.min.js"></script>
```

Then in the

```
$(document).ready
```

function I call $('.class').tokenize2() which throws the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tokenize2 is not a function
```

Again, it works fine when not in the SharePoint Modern Script Editor webpart. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I downloaded the tokenize2.js and changed line 9

`// AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
define(['jquery'], factory);`

to

`// AMD. Register as a named module.
define('myModule1', ['jquery'], factory);`

Previously I got an error that SharePoint did not like that it was being defined anonymously. So I added the name and now that error went away.

Comment: My current error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tokenize2 is not a function` persists.